# Understanding of JQuery Attr SRC of drag and drop image

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I've successfully implemented drag and drop function as below:

```
 var newThumb = document.createElement('IMG');
     $(newThumb).attr('src', evt.target.result);
     $(newThumb).attr('width', '100px');
     $(newThumb).attr('height', '100px');
     $(newThumb).css('margin', '10px');
     $(newThumb).click(function (e) {
         $(this).parent().children('IMG').removeClass('selected');
         $(this).addClass('selected');
             alert($(this).attr('src'));
         });
```

And below is the result of the alert:

[image]

May I know what kind of format is this and how can I to utilize them?

Comment: it is the base64 string encoded version of the image

Comment: what do you want to use it for?

Comment: @karthikr: If I'm to store this image to server, I am to store this string into the database? And somehow decode it and display it?

Comment: @NicolásStraubValdivieso: I'm trying to upload this drag and drop image to server and display them afterward

Comment: That is right. There is lots of help available on SO on how to do it.

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/drag-and-drop-to-server/